# The OracleParameterCollection only accepts non-null OracleParameter type objects, not OracleParameter objects

Tags: oracle11g, asp.net-4.0

I got the following error :

The OracleParameterCollection only accepts non-null OracleParameter type objects, not OracleParameter objects.

the code is something like this:

```
System.Data.Common.DbCommand dbCommand = Db.GetStoredProcCommand("ARCHIVE.FSP_STACKHOLDERSBYCREDENTIALS");
dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_Password", password));
```

My oracle DB is : 11gR2 x64 running on windows 7(x64)
My project is : .Net 4.0/Visual studio 2010 (build:any cpu)
IIS : 7.5 / app pool:default(asp.net4.0/integrated)
My ODP.Net comes from  : ODAC112021Xcopy_32bit

**NOTE** : I cannot change my Oracle.DataAccess.dll to x64 version becuase the project depends on some old dlls(it is because of changing to use the Oracle.DataAccess.dll x64 version, needs to chnage the PlatformTarget to x64 too)

so what should I do?
thanks in advance

Comment: is the value for password null in this case?

Comment: From the error I understand that the constructor you use fails to determine the corresponding OracleType for the passed password. You can try to use one of other constructors where you explicitly specify the OracleType and see if that resolves your problem

Comment: I changed the code to the following lines but the error did not changed : 

            var p = new OracleParameter();
            p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            p.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2;
            p.ParameterName = "P_UserName";
            p.Value = Convert.ToString(userName);
            dbCommand.Parameters.Add(p);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was on my own! I configed Db.GetStoredProcCommand() function improperly. which cause to create System.Data.Oracle.OracleCommand which comes from microsoft provider instead of oracle client provider.
But the text of exception was really misleading!